# I can't post in Django

Tags: django, web, django-models, django-forms

I can't post in Django, because when I import an image it doesn't work for me. it tells me that there's no file selected but I selected one.

This is the post model that I created, models.py file:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="post_images")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.caption
```

here's the forms.py file for the Post model:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class CreatePostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['caption','image']
```

here's the Publish function in views.py file which implements the logic for my publish feature:

```
@login_required
def Publish(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.publisher = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect("home")
    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()

    return render(request,"posts/publish.html",{
       "form":form,
    })
```

int the urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('publish/',views.Publish,name="publish"),
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
]
```

and here's in html template:

```
{% extends "users/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}create{% endblock title%}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5 authentification">
                <div class="form-header">
                    <h1>
                        publish
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="form-body">
                    <form method="POST">

                        <fieldset class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">publish</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

the Django version used is 2.2 and the Python 3.8. and Windows 10 Pro

Comment: the thing is not being saved in the database, when I try to publish an image, I select it and I write, when I click publish it tells me that there's no image selected.

Comment: that is because the `enctype` is missing in the HTML form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should alter the `.publisher` attribute of the *`.instance`* wrapped in the `form`, not the form itself, so:

```
@login_required
def Publish(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.publisher = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = CreatePostForm()

    return render(request,'posts/publish.html',{
       'form': form,
    })
```

Since you are submitting both files and data, you should specify the [**`enctype=…`** attribute [mdn]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) in the `<form>`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    …
</form>
```

---

> **Note**: Django's [**`DateTimeField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField)
> has a [**`auto_now_add=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField.auto_now_add)
> to work with timestamps. This will automatically assign the current datetime
> when creating the object, and mark it as non-editable (`editable=False`), such
> that it does not appear in `ModelForm`s by default.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).